# How to access excel data in django response for testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, xlwt

I have used `xlwt` for export some data to the client in django. Now i am testing the function and hence i want to verify that the data in response are matching with expected result.

How to read the excel data from the response object. The excel data is added to response something like `w.save(response)` and how to retrieve this data with the response in `response=self.client.get(reverse("create"))`?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? I'm not quite sure what you're wanting to test.

Comment: I am trying to verify that data in excel sheet and passed data to the function are same. So in test i am passing some data to my function and i have to verify it by reading the data in the response are same.